# How to parse out quoted values from a column with sql

Tags: sql, mysql, substr

I have a field that has values like this...

s:10:"03/16/1983";
s:4:"Male";
s:2:"No";

I'd like to parse out the quoted values.

its going to be some sort of combination of substr and instr

its the doublequote i have issues finding its position.

i have tried things like select substr(field_value, instr(field_value,'"'),instr(field_value,'"',null,2)) from table where etc

apologies a noob question...

Comment: i have tried things like select substr(field_value, instr(field_value,'"'),instr(field_value,'"',null,2)) from table where etc

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to do this in MySQL? It wouldn't be in my top ten choices for tools for this task...

Comment: Which database are you using? The answer will be different depending on if it's mysql vs sql server vs others.

Comment: True FDumlao -- PostgreSQL, for instance, can use full perl-style regular expressions. The tag does say MySQL, though, which supports a more limited regular expression syntax

Comment: mysql is the database.  i am familiar with regex though not within sql code.

Comment: Is it always three fields?  And are they always fields 10, 4 and 2 in that order?

Comment: Backslash is the escape character in MySQL, have you tried that out yet, i.e. instr(field_value,"\"")?

Comment: Edit to my comment: Use single quotes of course.

Comment: The bigger-picture answer is not to do this -- storing multiple values within a single field is a hint that your schema design is very, very wrong.

Comment: well i didnt design it and i have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work (unable to test at the moment):

```
select substr(substr(field_value, instr(field_value,':')+1, CHAR_LENGTH(field_value)-1),
              instr(substr(field_value, instr(field_value,':')+1, CHAR_LENGTH(field_value)-1),':')+1)
```

Edit: Putting my comment in the answer:

```
select substr(field_value, instr(field_value,'\"'),CHAR_LENGTH(field_value)-1)
```

Comment: this is perfect but i need what is in the double quotes not colons. that was more what i was having problems figuring out.  is it '"'? or do i escape it like "\""   in sql i have no idea.    thank you though! that helps me get closer!

Comment: What I was trying to do was use the fact that all your examples had the string after the second colon, then exploit that to grab the string, without ever messing around with the double quotes.  I don't like useing strategies that have to use specific knowledge like this, since it could change, but I've had to do it before.

Comment: ok then what about a regex find and replace to remove "s    ... or is that silly?

Comment: mysql is also telling me the len function does not exist.

Comment: i found it... in mysql it is CHAR_LENGTH instead of len

Comment: sorry, for MySQL it's Length(), I'll edit my answer.  Someone will probably come along and tell you how to escape out the double quotes, I just don't know off the top of my head.